# Htaccess Rewriting URL issue: how to distinguish Listing and detail page

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am developing an commerce site, Where users can post items in any categories (categories can be 2 to 4 levels).

I want to generate URL for listing and details pages:

- Listing page will show list of items in inner category
- Detail Page will show all information for item in inner category
  (Inner category means Last Category in hierarchic i.e. in `/classified/autos4x4s/mitsubishi/lancer/` inner mean "lancer")

Here are the links I want to generate

1. `/classified/autos4x4s/mitsubishi/lancer/` (for Listing)
2. `/classified/autos4x4s/mitsubishi/lancer/2011/3/12/lancer-2002-in-good-condition-14/` (for detail)

I want to redirect to ads.php if just 4 categories exist in URL and to detail.php if 6 items are passed (4 category name + 2 date and title).

I write these rules:

```
#listing ads
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/?$ ads.php?c1=$1&c2=$2&c3=$3&c4=$4 [NC,L]

#Detail pages
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/?$ detail.php?c1=$1&c2=$2&c3=$3&c4=$4&dt=$5&at=$6 [NC,L]
```

But all the sites page redirect to ads.php (Listing page) even home page.

I changes the rules as follow: (Even though I do not want to Use Listing and Detail in start of URL. Why as I see on some site as I want: `/classified/autos4x4s/mitsubishi/lancer/2011/3/12/lancer-2002-in-good-condition-14/`)

```
#Listing pages
RewriteRule ^Listing/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/?$ ads.php?c1=$1&c2=$2&c3=$3&c4=$4 [NC,L]

#Detail pages
RewriteRule ^Detail/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/?$ detail.php?c1=$1&c2=$2&c3=$3&c4=$4&dt=$5&at=$6 [NC,L]
```

Now all other pages are fine, but when I pass `/classified/autos4x4s/mitsubishi/lancer/2011/3/12/lancer-2002-in-good-condition-14/` it always goes to Listing page (ads.php) not to detail page.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: ok ThiefMaster, let me know, how to accept?

Comment: by clicking the checkmark icon next to an answer

Comment: www.example.com/classified/autos4x4s/mitsubishi/lancer/2011/3/12/lancer-2002-in-good-condition-14/ (for detail)     is as follow www.example.com/classified/autos4x4s/mitsubishi/lancer/2011-3-12/lancer-2002-in-good-condition-14/ (for detail) as date is a single entity

Answer (score 0):

Please watch out with the regex part:

```
(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)
```

The dot will match a '/' too, so for certain urls this leads to a combinatoric explosion of possible matches, making it very inefficient to rewrite. Please consider writing this part like any of these:

```
(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+*)/(\w+*)/(\w+*)/(\w+*)
([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)
```

Your question is related to this as well: a url containing 6 '/' characters will be matched by your 4 times slash pattern too (because . matches / as well)

Could you try:

```
#Listing pages
#e.g. /classified/autos4x4s/mitsubishi/lancer/
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/$ ads.php?c1=$1&c2=$2&c3=$3&c4=$4 [NC,L]

#Detail pages
#e.g. /classified/autos4x4s/mitsubishi/lancer/2011/3/12/lancer-2002-in-good-condition-14/ 
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\d+/\d+/\d+)/([^/]+)/$ detail.php?c1=$1&c2=$2&c3=$3&c4=$4&dt=$5&at=$6 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for Ur response, i already change it to /([^/]+).  NOW , as detail page url include date, so i resolve it writing a  tconditioo check for date value in url.      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.*)/.*/([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})/(.*)/.*
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?$  detail.php?&dt=%2&at=%3&c1=$1&c2=$2&c3=$3&c4=$4 [NC,L]
but failed to redirect for Listing page.

Comment: I try to negate above condition, as Listing page don't include date value, but its not working, and page not found error recieved. RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(.*)/.*/([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})/(.*)/.*
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?$  ads.php?c1=$1&c2=$2&c3=$3&c4=$4 [NC,L] but not working, Please help.

Comment: Hmmm. Your remarks are hard to read. Like said, having multiple .* parts in your pattern is _very_ not recommended. I don't understand why you use ? in your pattern ([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?, this is a bad idea because now you make the / optional and many combinations are possible again...

Comment: yes you are right it creates some other problems, but i want to Again it will be hard to read as no wYsiwYg EDITOR HERE. i WANT TO achieve this. I want to start form my sitename, then sitename\cars\, then sitename\cars\honda\, then sitename\cars\honda\Civic\ etc. a smoOth way, same for detail sitename\cars\honda\Civic\2011-04-07\excellent-car-for-sale\ just date, and title.